# how to show custom calendar with best style and design in android

Tags: android, android-xml, android-calendar

I want to show calendar in android app with style and design like in the picture below. How can I do that.
[image]

Comment: Whenever you are searching for custom view, use [this](https://android-arsenal.com/) website...

Comment: check my answer posted

Answer (score 1):

No need to use any library. android material design have this date picker already just try this code where you want to show this calendar...

```
int mYear, mMonth, mDay;
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(mContext, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                etdate.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
            }
        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

        datePickerDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [android-betterpickers](https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers) library for that.

You can customize as per your requirements.

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

```
       compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:1.5.3'

  final Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    dob_value = i2 + "-" + (i1 + 1) + "-" + i;
                    DateFormat formatter;
                    Date date1 = null;
                    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                    try {
                        date1 = formatter.parse(dob_value);
                        Date d = formatter.parse(formatter.format(new Date()));
                        if (Utill.getYear(date1, d) >= Utill.age_limit) {
                            dob_value = i + "-" + (i1 + 1) + "-" + i2;
                            dob_tv.setText(dob_value);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.age_min) + "" + Utill.age_limit + " " + getResources().getString(R.string.str_years), 50).show();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            };

            DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                    dateSetListener,
                    now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            );
            dpd.setAccentColor(Color.parseColor("#ffc63939"));

            dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
```